# What's the simplest way to make a SQL query to generate cumulative subscribers?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, count, time-series

I have a `subscriptions` table (in postgresql) with the columns `subscribed_at` and `unsubscribed_at`. I'd like to write a simple query that produces a list of the cumulative subscriber count (subscribed minus unsubscribed as of that date) for each month end.

Each row is essentially querying: if the group_by month is "January-2020" how many subscriptions have `subscribed_at` date with a month on or before January 2020, and a `unsubscribed_at` date of null or after January 2020.

I'm just not familiar enough with SQL to know the right syntax here.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Table**

```
+----+------+---------------+-----------------+
| id | name | subscribed_at | unsubscribed_at |
+----+------+---------------+-----------------+
|  1 | John | '2020-01-08'  | null            |
|  2 | Mary | '2020-01-09'  | '2020-01-20'    |
|  3 | Jeff | '2020-01-10'  | null            |
|  4 | Bill | '2020-02-02'  | null            |
|  5 | Bob  | '2020-02-08   | '2020-02-21'    |
+----+------+---------------+-----------------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', subscribed_at) as month,
COUNT(*) as subscribers
FROM subscriptions
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

**Desired Output**

```
+---------------+-------------+
|     month     | subscribers |
+---------------+-------------+
| January 2020  |           2 |
| February 2020 |           3 |
+---------------+-------------+
```

Where `subscribers` is the cumulative net subscribers at the end of that month.

Here is a SQLFiddle with the data and query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd7725/1

Comment: Hi, please, read through this [Tips for SQL Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/460557) and update your question accordingly

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos! Updated. Is that better?

Comment: Way better and I see you already got your answers for it :) Thank you. Please don't forget to mark the one that better solve your problem as the Accepted one. You can do it by clicking on the "V" icon on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `generate_series()` to enumerate all months between the first subscription start and the latest subscription end, and then a lateral join to compute the active subscriptions count.

```
select d.dt, n.no_active_subscriptions
from (
    select generate_series(
        date_trunc('month', min(subscribed_at)), 
        date_trunc('month', max(unsubsribed_at)), 
        interval '1 month'
    ) dt
    from subscriptions
) d
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) no_active_subscriptions
    from subscriptions s
    where 
        s.subscribed_at < d.dt + interval '1 month' 
        and (s.unsubscribed_at >= d.dt or s.unsubscribed_at is null)
) n
```

Comment: Thank you @GMB, but if I run this in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd7725/3) the results I get are 3 and 4 (when the expected results are 2 and 3)

Comment: @ruby86: OK, I wasn't sure how you wanted to count subscriptions that start and end within the same month. You can get the result that you want by just chaing the `where` clause of the `lateral join`: `where  s.subscribed_at < d.dt + interval '1 month' and (s.unsubscribed_at >= d.dt + interval '1 month' or s.unsubscribed_at is null)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach.  Calculate +1 on the date someone starts and -1 on the date the stop.  Then do a cumulative sum.

For the end of the month, take the last record per month:

```
with s as (
      select dte, sum(inc) ondate, sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte) as subs
      from subscriptions s cross join lateral
           (values (subscribed_at, 1), (unsubscribed_at, -1)
           ) v(dte, inc)
      where v.dte is not null
      group by v.dte
     )
 select distinct on (date_trunc('month', dte)) *
 from s
 order by date_trunc('month', dte), dte desc;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd7725/7) is a db<>fiddle.

This may be exactly what you want . . . or you might want to tweak it.

1. The date you stop counting might be the day *after* the stop.  If so, add one date in the subquery.
2. If you want to report on the last day of the month, you can use the expression `(date_trunc('month', dte) + interval '1 month - 1 day')::date`.