# Best way to calculate aggregates from an intervals table in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Assuming we have a table like the following:

```sql
create table subscriptions 
(
start_date Date,
end_date Date,
customer_id Int64
)
engine = MergeTree()
order by (customer_id, start_date, end_date);


insert into subscriptions values ('2023-01-01', '2023-01-04', 1);
insert into subscriptions values ('2023-01-02', '2023-02-01', 2);
insert into subscriptions values ('2023-01-04', '2023-01-10', 3);
```

what's the best way to calculate the number of subscribers per date in Clickhouse?

I already have some SQL query similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62583654/21124361
but I am wondering whether I could utilize some special function of Clickhouse.

Outcome should be:

```sql
| date | subscribers |
| -------- | -------- |
| 2023-01-01   | 1   |
| 2023-01-02   | 2   |
| 2023-01-03   | 2   |
| 2023-01-04   | 3   |
| 2023-01-05   | 2   |
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT
    day,
    toDate(day) AS date,
    uniq(customer_id)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        arrayJoin(range(toUInt32(start_date), toUInt32(end_date) + 1)) AS day,
        customer_id
    FROM subscriptions
)
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY date ASC

/*
┌───day─┬───────date─┬─uniq(customer_id)─┐
│ 19358 │ 2023-01-01 │                 1 │
│ 19359 │ 2023-01-02 │                 2 │
│ 19360 │ 2023-01-03 │                 2 │
│ 19361 │ 2023-01-04 │                 3 │
│ 19362 │ 2023-01-05 │                 2 │
│ 19363 │ 2023-01-06 │                 2 │
│ 19364 │ 2023-01-07 │                 2 │
│ 19365 │ 2023-01-08 │                 2 │
│ 19366 │ 2023-01-09 │                 2 │
│ 19367 │ 2023-01-10 │                 2 │
│ 19368 │ 2023-01-11 │                 1 │
│ 19369 │ 2023-01-12 │                 1 │
│ 19370 │ 2023-01-13 │                 1 │
│ 19371 │ 2023-01-14 │                 1 │
│ 19372 │ 2023-01-15 │                 1 │
│ 19373 │ 2023-01-16 │                 1 │
│ 19374 │ 2023-01-17 │                 1 │
│ 19375 │ 2023-01-18 │                 1 │
│ 19376 │ 2023-01-19 │                 1 │
│ 19377 │ 2023-01-20 │                 1 │
│ 19378 │ 2023-01-21 │                 1 │
│ 19379 │ 2023-01-22 │                 1 │
│ 19380 │ 2023-01-23 │                 1 │
│ 19381 │ 2023-01-24 │                 1 │
│ 19382 │ 2023-01-25 │                 1 │
│ 19383 │ 2023-01-26 │                 1 │
│ 19384 │ 2023-01-27 │                 1 │
│ 19385 │ 2023-01-28 │                 1 │
│ 19386 │ 2023-01-29 │                 1 │
│ 19387 │ 2023-01-30 │                 1 │
│ 19388 │ 2023-01-31 │                 1 │
│ 19389 │ 2023-02-01 │                 1 │
└───────┴────────────┴───────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @vladimir. On an actual table it thrown OOM though, probably because some intervals might be for a few years. So I guess the `range` becomes problematic? Do you think there is a more efficient way or native CH function to handle such tables?